# Using red wire for smart thermostat voltage

Tags: thermostat-c-wire

I want to add a smart thermostat. Why can’t I use the red wire voltage for the c wire? I’ve read where some say red wire is intermittent voltage, but mines constant.

Comment: We're going to need a bit more information, like the model number of the thermostat and type of  heating/cooling system.

Comment: I agree, this question is not complete and needs more background and details.  You are looking at your setup, assuming everyone else's setup is exactly like yours, and that we'll know what you're talking about. We don't, sorry.

Comment: My apologies. My thermostat is currently a 4 wire setup with the red wire (hot wire) connected to the R and a jumper wire between the R & Rh. The current thermostat is a “toptech”. The system is a ruud. I hope that helps.

Comment: The wire colors are standards but if your system was not properly wired the power could be on the lilac colored wire. We really need to know more about your system (note some are 2 wire normally red white, 4 wire up to 7 wire is not unusual) we need to know more about your system prior to providing advise.

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring at both the thermostat and furnace ends please?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't encountered the intermittent comment before, typically the R terminal in the furnace is +24vac, usually using red wire to the R on the stat. If using a tester on vdc setting the display will be erratic.

There is no *code* for color thermostats (or most other devices less than 50V).

But a trade standard many techs use Red for the R +24 hot , White for W heat switchleg, Green for G fan switchleg, Yellow for the Y cooling switchleg.

Historically there has been no use of the C 0vac common at the stat, so no real standard has developed, just using any left over wire or stealing the green fan control wire if only 4 wires are available and reterminating both ends of the green on C.

But if somebody has a cable with a different color set, like a 4 wire phone cable, any color swap can be used so it is absolutely necessary to document the old terminations before disconnecting the stat. Wire tags are good, pictures are great. If your documents fail you can usually recreate or confirm colors by looking at the furnace end of the cable, those terminals will be marked.

Answer (score 0):

the R  wire is like phase and the C wire is like neutral.

Smart switches need a neutral connection, so that there's power for the internal circuitry, and for the same reason smart thermostats need the C wire.